# How to get current location gmap...?

Tags: javascript

```
function initialize() { 
  var mapProp = { center:new google.maps.LatLng(5,-5), zoom:5,   mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
  var map=new   google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapContainer"),mapProp); 
}  

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

i want get the current latitude and longitude

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code

```
if (navigator.geolocation){
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(callBackFunc);
}

function callBackFunc(position){
    var _lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var _lon = position.coords.longitude;   
}
```

Comment: function initialize(position)
{  
 var _lat = position.coords.latitude;  
    var _lon = position.coords.longitude;  
var mapProp = {
  center:new google.maps.LatLng(_lat,_lon),
  zoom:5,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapContainer"),mapProp);
}

if (navigator.geolocation){
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); not working

Comment: is there any way to get the latitude and longitude in same function.in initiaize function not from other?

Comment: function initialize(position) { 
    var _lat = position.coords.latitude; 
    var _lon = position.coords.longitude; 
    var mapProp = { center:new google.maps.LatLng(_lat,_lon), zoom:5, mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP }; 
    var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapContainer"),mapProp);
};

function loadMaps(){
    if (navigator.geolocation){         navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize);
                              } 
};
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', loadMaps);

Comment: <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false"> i use this link above code